# Rails controller between range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to find all advertisement between the two date to limit what I see and what I don't see

Here the model

```
Advertiser
#  publishon            :date
#  publishoff           :date
```

The controller look has follow

```
@advertisments = Advertiser.where("publishon >= ? AND publishoff <= ?", Date.today, Date.today)
```

For some reason it doesn't grab it, do i need to change the format of Date.today?

Comment: Do you mean Advertisement.where?

Comment: Are you getting a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception, or something else? Are you sure you have data in your database that satisfies the criteria you specify?

Comment: No its Actually Advertiser, also i place the following code in <% if @advertisments.nil? %> in my views in case nothing is selected, but if i do advertiser,first it works

Comment: it should be `<% unless @advertisments.nil? %>`

Comment: I did unless and i get the following error undefined method `adone' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation where adone is an other property of advertiser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query, your dates are probably going to be converted to DateTimes. Check your log for the SQL generated to verify, but if so, you're querying:

```
>= Wed, 10 Apr 2013 00:00 && <= Wed, 10 Apr 2013 00:00
```

You probably have hours and minutes set on your Advertisement dates. Try

```
(..., Date.today, Date.tomorrow)
```

Be sure to add specs or regression tests that ensure you are only able to select within a 24-hour period.

Comment: Here is the sql query generated by my selection SELECT `advertisers`.* FROM `advertisers` WHERE (publishon >= '2013-04-10' AND publishoff <= '2013-04-10')

Comment: What's the type on the `publishon` and `publishoff` columns?

Comment: From the schema file they are  t.date     "publishon"  t.date     "publishoff"

Comment: The actual result will be DB-dependent. Can you get data from raw DB queries?

Comment: Yeah i did look at the field this is publishon of the database i am publishon: "2013-01-13", this is from the consoler